# How to login with python and requests on pw.mail.ru

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program to **scrape** some data from https://pw.mail.ru/ but can not login.
My target page is https://pw.mail.ru/supermarathon.php

I tried different libs and guides, but I guess nothing is simple with this one.

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': 'smth',
    'password': 'smthpass'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://pw.mail.ru/supermarathon.php', data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://pw.mail.ru/supermarathon.php')
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

I'm getting code from the page, but I can see that it did not log in,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I used the workaround by authorizing on mail.ru and passing that to pw.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use selenium & chromedriver instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_path = "Path/to/your/chromedriver.exe" # you can download it on https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
# Passing url to chromedriver
url = 'https://pw.mail.ru/supermarathon.php'
driver.get(url)
# Passing user-password to the form
driver.find_element_by_id('nrLogin_auth').send_keys('your_email')
driver.find_element_by_id('nrPassword_auth').send_keys('your_password')
# Click the submit button
driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit_auth').click
```

Then you can use any web scraping library, like BeautifulSoup.
Just pass the page source code to it.

```
driver.page_source # this is the page HTML code
```

Also, you can pass the parameters to requests, but it depends on the site you are trying to access. Not all sites support this feature.

Comment: I know about selenium, but I'd like to keep it in console and get around mail.ru cookie protection.